# Python3 - Iterate over object methods with similar names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate a list of object methods with similar names. Is there any clever way I can do this. I have objects similar to this but would like to use an iterator instead of just making a list of functions.

```
dog1.feed()
dog2.feed()
dog3.feed()
dog4.feed()
dog5.feed()
...
```

Comment: You're probably better off using a list or dict of objects instead of putting each one in a separate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All local object names are in `locals()`:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    locals()["dog" + str(i)].feed()
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for!

Is there a way I can do this in a function? 

dog1.feed()
dog2.feed()
dog3.feed()
dog4.feed()
dog5.feed()

def feeddogs():
    for i in range(1,6):
    locals()["dog" + str(i)].feed()

Comment: Sorry, just figured this out. Used globals() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string concatenation to do what's basically an `eval`. Just put your dogs in a list:

```
for dog in [dog1, dog2,...,dogn]:
  dog.feed()
```

Or, abusing the list comprehension syntax a little:

```
[dog.feed() for dog in [dog1, dog2,...,dogn]
```